# How to solve kernel error in Jupyter notebook? (win64)

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I am kinda new to Jupyter notebooks. I am getting a kernel error on the top right corner of the notebook (Python 3), also I can't run any code.

This is the error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\LAM\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\web.py", line 1699, in _execute
        result = await result
      File "C:\Users\LAM\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 742, in run
        yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)  # type: ignore
      File "C:\Users\LAM\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\handlers.py", line 72, in post
        type=mtype))
      File "C:\Users\LAM\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 735, in run
        value = future.result()
      File "C:\Users\LAM\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 742, in run
        yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)  # type: ignore
      File "C:\Users\LAM\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\sessionmanager.py", line 88, in create_session
        kernel_id = yield self.start_kernel_for_session(session_id, path, name, type, kernel_name)
      File "C:\Users\LAM\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 735, in run
        value = future.result()
      File "C:\Users\LAM\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 742, in run
        yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)  # type: ignore
      File "C:\Users\LAM\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\sessionmanager.py", line 101, in start_kernel_for_session
        self.kernel_manager.start_kernel(path=kernel_path, kernel_name=kernel_name)
      File "C:\Users\LAM\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 735, in run
        value = future.result()
      File "C:\Users\LAM\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 209, in wrapper
        yielded = next(result)
      File "C:\Users\LAM\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\kernels\kernelmanager.py", line 168, in start_kernel
        super(MappingKernelManager, self).start_kernel(**kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\LAM\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\multikernelmanager.py", line 110, in start_kernel
        km.start_kernel(**kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\LAM\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\manager.py", line 240, in start_kernel
        self.write_connection_file()
      File "C:\Users\LAM\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\connect.py", line 547, in write_connection_file
        kernel_name=self.kernel_name
      File "C:\Users\LAM\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\connect.py", line 212, in write_connection_file
        with secure_write(fname) as f:
      File "C:\Users\LAM\Anaconda3\lib\contextlib.py", line 112, in __enter__
        return next(self.gen)
      File "C:\Users\LAM\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\connect.py", line 102, in secure_write
        with os.fdopen(os.open(fname, open_flag, 0o600), mode) as f:
    PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\LAM\\AppData\\Roaming\\jupyter\\runtime\\kernel-a1df27b5-fc61-47a3-9f67-f3a880aeb05c.json'
```

Comment: Looks like you've hit this issue: https://github.com/jupyter/jupyter_client/issues/479 . If so, the fix is to upgrade the `jupyter_core` package. Assuming that's installed with conda, you can do that by opening an Anaconda command prompt and running `conda update jupyter_core`.

Comment: Please, go to your provider for assistance on your product.  This forum is about programming, you have tagged as `C` a question that has nothing to do with that language.

Comment: if i uninstalling anaconda and try to install it again , Will it solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Please try out by creating a new conda environment. Create conda environment using the command :

```
conda create -n <env_name> -c intel python=3.6
```

Activate the environmemt using the command :

```
source activate <env_name>
```

Please install the required packages in this environment. Kindly install the ipykernal using the command:

```
conda install ipykernel
ipython kernel install --name <env_name> --user
```

Select the installed ipykernal from your jupyter notebook. Hope this helps.

Please refer the following link, https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/2301